# Subtract colums from two tables

Tags: mysql

There are two tables from which i need to get total available quantity

```
Table T1
+-------------+------------+  
| Code        | Qty        |  
+-------------+------------+  
| A           | 500        |  
+-------------+------------+    


Table T2
+-------------+------------+  
| Code        | Qty        |  
+-------------+------------+  
| A           | 10         |  
+-------------+------------+    
| A           | 20         |  
+-------------+------------+
```

With this code i get result 970 instead of 470:

```
SELECT
  `T1`.`Code`,
  (IFNULL(Sum(`T1`.`Qty`),0) - IFNULL(Sum(`T2`.`Qty`),0)) AS TotalQty
FROM
  `T1`
  LEFT JOIN `T2` ON `T1`.`Code` =
    `T2`.`Code`
GROUP BY
  `T1`.`Code`
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to check my Answer Below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code :)

SELECT Code,IFNULL(SUM(Qty),0)-IFNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM T2 WHERE T1.Code = Code),0) AS answer FROM T1 GROUP BY Code

i edit my answer incase that you want to add a condition base on Code and also to prevent returning of null value try this bro

Comment: This works perfect but only for one code. My table have many other codes. I need a list of all the codes and their total quantities.

Comment: @Josef try this

SELECT (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(QTY),0) - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM T2 WHERE Code=T1.Code),0) FROM T1  GROUP BY Code ) AS answer

Comment: Still the same result. I just don't get it, checked at least 5 times... I'm getting error /* SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row */

Comment: @Josef Here's my final ANSWER

SELECT Code,IFNULL(SUM(Qty),0)-IFNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM T2 WHERE T1.Code = Code),0) AS answer FROM T1 GROUP BY Code

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
SELECT
  `T1`.`Code`,
  (IFNULL(`T1`.`Qty`,0) - IFNULL(Sum(`T2`.`Qty`),0)) AS TotalQty
FROM
  `T1`
  LEFT JOIN `T2` ON `T1`.`Code` =
    `T2`.`Code`
GROUP BY
  `T1`.`Code`
```

You will get 470.

Comment: This works fine, but if I have in T1 more same codes it doesn't summarize them all, only first one.

Comment: Ok..I didnt know about that.

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate rows in Table T1.it means T1 has another record with A 500

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT
  `T1`.`Code`, IFNULL(`T1`.`Qty`,0) - SUM(IFNULL(`T2`.`Qty`,0)
FROM
   T1
LEFT JOIN 
  T2 USING Code
GROUP BY Code
```

Comment: @Josef try my Ansewr below